# MVC: I made a addquestion method in my repository that call .addobject(); and savechanges();

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, model-view-controller, repository

I made a method addquestion that calls addobject() and savechanges()

the Code inside the method is following:

> ```
> public class AdminRepository
> {
>     Model1Container db = new Model1Container();
>     CreateViewModel rep = new CreateViewModel();
>
>     public void Question addquestion() // <-- I dont know how the method should be
>     {
>         Question q = new Question();
>
>         q.QuestionText = rep.QuestionText;
>
>         db.Question.AddObject(q);
>         db.SaveChanges();
>     }
> ```

I know that the code is right but I dont know how to define the method.

Thanks in advance!

Best Regards!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are specifying both a return type of `void` and `Question`

Since you aren't actually returning anything inside your method, the correct return type is `void`

```
public void addquestion()
{
   //Your code here
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
public void AddQuestion()
{
    ....
}
```